# -XX:HeapDumpPath option in jvm config not working

Tags: java, linux, jvm

-XX:HeapDumpPath not working when kill -3.

```
java -server -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:+UseG1GC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:{GC_PATH} -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath={HEAP_PATH} -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local app.jar
```

gc log printed in correct {GC_PATH}. But Heapdump printed in stdout.

Is any wrong in my jvm config OR Doesn't work when kill -3 ??

Comment: What shell is interpreting that command line?

Comment: I used default bash shell.

Comment: So what are using the {...} for in that context?  That doesn't look like valid bash syntax to me.

Comment: I used correct path. In that context, I just hided it.

Comment: -XX:HeapDumpPath=/abc/def/heap.dumps, 
-XX:HeapDumpPath="/abc/def/heap.dumps"

Anything not working

Comment: `-XX` options are not supported by all versions.  Check that first.

Comment: Also check that there is enough space in the file system.  I have a feeling that `java` might avoid writing a dump file if it is likely to fill up the file system.

Comment: *"But Heapdump printed in stdout."* - Heap dumps are never printed on stdout. You probably confuse thread dumps with heap dumps.

Comment: @apangin you are right. I confused because heap status under thread dumps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HeapDumpPath` affects only automatic heap dumps generated in response to one of the following options:

- `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`
- `-XX:+HeapDumpBeforeFullGC`
- `-XX:+HeapDumpAfterFullGC`

It has no effect on heap dumps generated by other means, e.g. `jmap` command or `dumpHeap` operation called via JMX.

Also `HeapDumpPath` has no effect on **thread** dumps. In particular, `kill -3` will print thread stacks on `stdout` of the Java process. If you want to dump threads to the given file, use `jstack`.